# Передача данных через activityViewController в виде таблицы

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift3

Хочу шэрить через activityViewController несколько значений в виде таблицы, чтоб красиво было, примерно так...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А получается просто по очереди столбцами вниз. Есть три параметра, хранящие значения в массивах.

```
let name = ["Андрей", "Виктор", "Сергей", "Олег"] 
let weight = ["60", "70", "80", "90"] 
let height = ["160", "170", "180", "190"]

let people = String(format: "Были три товарища: \n Имя    Вес     Рост\n%@", arguments: [name.joined(separator: "\n"), weight.joined(separator: "\n"), height.joined(separator: "\n")])
let activityViewController: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [people], applicationActivities: nil)
self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас не верный формат строки:

```
arguments: [name.joined(separator: "\n"), weight.joined(separator: "\n"), height.joined(separator: "\n")]
```

Вы после каждого значения добавляете переход на новую строку **"\n"**. его нужно добавить только после последнего элемента в строке (вес).